# Plot quantile regression with xtqreg Stata command?

Tags: plot, panel, stata, quantile, quantile-regression

Is there a way to plot quantile regression lines specifically with the *xtqreg* Stata package? *xtqreg* computes quantile regressions with fixed effects:   https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s458523.html

Comment: I don't think either author is a member here, so we are all just looking at the same help. I imagine you need to save predictions to new variables using the options. This kind of question is much better directed to Statalist, which the second author does watch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much value in plotting the coefficients associated with xtqreg.
in principle, all coefficients have the following form:

b(t)=b_loc+b_scale*error_quantile.

This means that all coefficients across quantiles will show the same "trend"

see this example:

```
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/o/oaxaca.dta, clear
ssc install mmqreg
forvalues i=5(5)95 {
    mmqreg lnwage educ exper tenure female, q(`i')
    matrix bb=nullmat(bb)/[e(b),`i']
}
svmat bb, 
line bb11 bb16
```

So, couple of things here.

mmqreg is similar to xtqreg but you can use it even if there are no fixed effects. (as in the example above).

bb11 corresponds to the coefficient of education across quantiles

bb16 is the quantile of interest.

An update:
There is now a new command available from SSC called "qregplot". it works similarly to "grqreg", but will plot Qregression coefficients from other commands including xtqreg and mmqreg.

For the example above:

```
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/o/oaxaca.dta, clear
ssc install mmqreg
mmqreg lnwage educ exper tenure female, q(10)
qregplot
```